# C# - Can you iterate through every element in an irregular JSON string to find a named element at any depth?

Tags: c#, recursion, json.net

```
[{
        "CustomerId": 1,
        "Country": "Germany"
    }, {
        "CustomerId": 2,
        "Country": "Spain"
    }, {
        "CustomerId": 3,
        "courses": [
            {"Country": "Vanuatu"},
            {"Country": "France"}
        ]
    }
]
```

With an irregularly structured JSON file like this, is it possible to iterate through the data and read the value of the `"Country"` element, no matter how deep in the structure it is?

The examples I can find all use fixed classes which push the data into objects.   I've tried using `JArray` and `JObject` to iterate through the data but they like a fixed structure too, so I can't get them to work.

I could use a `JArray` and then endlessly loop through every sub-element, but that seems inefficient and it feels like there should be a better way.

Comment: Is that the only data you want form the JSON string? In that case it's better to use the JsonReader-like classes of your parser to read until you find `Country` properties and read their values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid recursion or iterating over all elements. One option is to use JsonPath :

```
var o=JArray.Parse(json);
var tokens=o.SelectTokens("$..Country");
foreach(var  token in tokens)
{
    Console.WriteLine(token);
}
```

This prints

```
Germany
Spain
Vanuatu
France
```

**Avoid deserialization**

If the countries are the only data you want to extract from a large document, you can use JsonReader to extract just the countries without deserializing the entire string:

```
    var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        if(reader.TokenType==JsonToken.PropertyName && (string)reader.Value=="Country")
        {
            //Read the property value
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadAsString());
        }
    }
```

This can be converted to an iterator method to reduce clutter:

```
public IEnumerable<String> GetAllCountries(string json)
{
    var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        if(reader.TokenType==JsonToken.PropertyName && (string)reader.Value=="Country")
        {
            yield reader.ReadAsString;
        }
    }
}
```

**Cheaper with System.Text.Json**

The previous code reads every property name which means a new temporary string object is allocated for every property. This could be avoided if `Value` was a `ReadOnlySpan<char>` but JSON.NET only returns a string.

In System.Text.Json, the [Utf8JsonReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/use-utf8jsonreader) class can work on UTF8 bytes directly, avoiding copies and temporary strings as much as possible. In ASP.NET Core, it works directly on the bytes received in an HTTP request.

Let's assume the JSON data was loaded as bytes, eg from a file or requests (in this case I used `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()`. The following code reads from that array *without* making copies, not even to compare the property names :

```
    var reader = new Utf8JsonReader(new ReadOnlySequence<byte>(jsonBytes));
    while(reader.Read())
    {
        if( reader.TokenType==JsonTokenType.PropertyName 
            && reader.ValueTextEquals("Country"))
        {
            reader.Read();
            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString());
        }
    }
```

STJ uses Span, ReadOnlySpan etc to effectively look directly at parts of the original buffer instead of copying data out of the buffer. Even [ValueTextEquals](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Reader/Utf8JsonReader.cs#L465) converts the parameter to a Span before comparing it directly against the source bytes

Answer (score 1):

you can use recursion for this, you can use [NewtonSoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) library for this.

you need to check if the element is of type `JTokenType.Object` or `JTokenType.Array`

```
public static void FindElement(JToken jToken, string name)
{
    if (jToken.Type == JTokenType.Object)
    {
        foreach (var property in jToken.Children<JProperty>())
        {
            if (property.Name == name)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{name}: {property.Value}");
            }

            FindElement(property.Value, name);
        }
    }
    else if (jToken.Type == JTokenType.Array)
    {
        foreach (var item in jToken.Children())
        {
            FindElement(item, name);
        }
    }
}

JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(json);
FindElement(jsonArray, "Country");
```

**Output:**

[image]